# BigQuery API Connection in Sheets (Potential Caching)

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-sheets-api

My team is currently running an Flask API Script from the Google Cloud Console that updates a BigQuery table every 15 minutes.

We are using sheets to pull the results from that table and and display it with visual tools from sheets.

This full sheets ecosystem looks like this:

- A sheets document has a linked project that has a JS-like file that
  has been saved as a shared library.
- All other sheets in the ecosystem that are used for displaying tables use the above mentioned shared library to work with BigQuery.
- The shared library facilitates the connection to BigQuery and the uploading of its static formatted response to a static location
  in the sheet, which will then update the visuals of the sheet.
- Outside the shared library each sheet has its own timezone, BigQuery dataset name, and BigQuery table name defined as a variable.
- The shared library uses these variables to grab the correct BigQuery tables information.
- All of the sheets have been checked for BigQuery connection API turned on, and verified they are linked to the same Cloud Console
  project where the BigQuery dataset is held.

This is the issue I am facing:

For a few weeks all was working as expected in this ecosystem. Then one day inexplicably the BigQuery table, which updates every minute, completely stopped updating. I first went to check the Cloud Console server where my Flask project is running (outside of sheets) to update the BigQuery source table. The Flask server was on time and the BigQuery data was up to date.

The data tracks metrics through out the day, so I can tell the BigQuery table is updated if it has data for the current hour. So if its 4:36 PM I can expect the table to have data for around 4:15 PM at the very least. In this case the BigQuery table is actually up to date, but the sheet was not up to date (4-5 hours behind).

This prompted me to check the BigQuery connection in sheets and log out the results. This is where things got very weird. I was getting the snap shot of the BigQuery table from 4 hours ago. As I said before I manually checked the table and the actual BigQuery table was up to date.

I fixed this error by copy and pasting my exact code into a new function and re-naming it. When I ran the new function, which had identical code, but a different function name, the table no longer pulled an old "cached" version of the BigQuery table but instead pulled the correct values.

I can only imagine that there is some sort of caching going on in the native sheets-BigQuery api integration. I am also confused by the fact that I have 9 of these environments running in parallel and only 2 of them were effected. They are all running exactly the same code and all have been verified to be pulling from correctly updated BigQuery tables but only 2 randomly fell behind pulling the same table for 4 hours. Now this completely looks like a caching problem but I have no way to actually test as I have no insight into the BigQuery API library that is native to sheets.

**What I would like know is can I somehow add a cache buster or something to the BigQuery request to be sure this doesn't happen?**

**I have the table checking for updates on cron every 1 minute to make sure it updates as often as possible as it is a realtime visual update application. Would lowering the cron help with this cacheing issue?**

Comment: if you don't get answer in 2 days ping me at gmail eventually will try to connect with some support personel

Comment: This feels like a GCP Support issue, so we can check internal metrics or other tools to help you with this. In case you have a support package you can submit a case [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/), if not, you can create an issue in *IssueTracker* following [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164&template=803901).